# how to write shell script for USB drive

Tags: command-line, scripts, usb-drive

Currently, I am writing the Shell script for USB drive in linux. I am planning to do following tasks.

1) Auto detect newly connected usb drive and execute the next procedure.

2) If the multiple usb drive connected to the system. Find the specific usb drive from its name. (I wrote the code for this and it is working)

3) Copy the path (/dev/sdc1 or sdb1 or other) of the specific USB drive and use this for mounting the usb drive in linux.

4) after mounting the USB drive, compare the similar folder from USB drive and desktop, if the folders are different, copy the data from USB drive to the desktop folder and reboot system.

It will be great, if you suggest me the way. Sorry if I miss something.

Best Regards

Comment: Are you just asking us for `rsync` ?

Comment: @guiverc yes, I want to write auto-sync program for specific usb drive.

Comment: @user68186 I am using Xubuntu 18.04 version

Comment: @user68186 currently, I am able to identify the specific usb drive from multiple drives by its name. I will write the code to mount it automatically, if i know the path of it and I don't have idea to get the path of it.

Comment: @user68186 path is like "/dev/sdc1 or sdb1 or other"

Comment: The USB should auto mount on insertion.